# Update data from a DataTable table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, datatable

I can not properly update my table (datatable).

PHP code :

```
function test(){
 echo '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>';
}
```

JavaScript code (test.php) :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    data: "refresh="+escape(refresh),
    url: "test.php",
    success: function(msg){
        $("#conf-security-filter-table-"+list).dataTable().fnClearTable();
        $("#conf-security-filter-table-"+list).dataTable().fnAddData(msg);
        $("#conf-security-filter-table-"+list).dataTable().fnDraw();
    }
})
```

Currently with this code table is updated but consider "msg" as an array:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
  <  |   t  |   r  |   >
```

Is there a way to exploit this array ?

Comment: I bypassed my problem using prepend after destroying the table.
I am therefore obliged to redefine the table properties.

Also disadvantage, I have set the width of columns which were all small after refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing with the code k... check this link it will help you before that get some clear idea about ajax [example](http://www.codeforest.net/simple-search-with-php-jquery-and-mysql)